# Interface and type casting

Tags: java

In the Java 8 tutorial about interface, [one example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) says that when a class implements an interface, one has to type cast the interface type into the class type in order to invoke methods of this class, as shown by the following example from the java 8 tutorial:

```
public class RectanglePlus 
    implements Relatable {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

    // four constructors
    public RectanglePlus() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public RectanglePlus(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }
    public RectanglePlus(int w, int h) {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public RectanglePlus(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    // a method for computing
    // the area of the rectangle
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    // a method required to implement
    // the Relatable interface
    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        RectanglePlus otherRect 
            = (RectanglePlus)other;
        if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
            return -1;
        else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;               
    }
}
```

In the method `isLargerThan(Relatable other)`, other is casted to type RectanglePlus in order to invoke `getArea()`.
In the [other example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/examples/defaultmethods/StandardDeck.java) about default methods in interface, the `compareTo(Card o)` method doesn't type cast o to type PlayingCard, but can invoke `int hashCode()` directly, I don't understand this. Thanks for your help.

```
package defaultmethods; 

public class PlayingCard implements Card {

    private Card.Rank rank;
    private Card.Suit suit;

    public PlayingCard(Card.Rank rank, Card.Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Card.Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Card.Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Card) {
            if (((Card)obj).getRank() == this.rank &&
                ((Card)obj).getSuit() == this.suit) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return ((suit.value()-1)*13)+rank.value();
    }

    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        return this.hashCode() - o.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.rank.text() + " of " + this.suit.text();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new PlayingCard(Rank.ACE, Suit.DIAMONDS);
        new PlayingCard(Rank.KING, Suit.SPADES);
    }
}
```

Comment: hashCode() is defined in java.lang.Object. You can call that method on any object.

Comment: What methods does `Card` declare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Because `hashCode` is defined in [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) and every other class extends `Object` implicitly.

So when you have

```
public int compareTo(Card o) {
    return this.hashCode() - o.hashCode();
}
```

the compiler already knows that `o` is of type `Card` which extends `Object` which defines a `hashCode` method. No need for an explicit cast.

On the other hand in your `isLargerThan` method the parameter is of type `Relatable`:

```
public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
    RectanglePlus otherRect 
        = (RectanglePlus)other;
    if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
        return -1;
    else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;               
}
```

And judging from the link you provided, the `getArea` method is defined in `RectanglePlus` only. Since the compiler only sees `Relatable` it does not know anything about a `getArea` method at this point and you need to explicitly cast `other` to `RectanglePlus` to be able to access it.

Note that you should actually do an `instanceof` check *before* casting to avoid a `ClassCastException` when `other` is not a `RectanglePlus` (you don't know if there might be other classes implementing `Relatable`).

Let me try a non-code related example:

If people have a pet they usually give it a name. So whatever pet you have, one can always ask for its name (cf. `hashCode`). But they cannot ask you to make it *bark* (cf. `getArea`) unless they know that it is a dog.
And you will probably fail to make a cat *bark* (cf. `ClassCastException`).